# MySQL select with where takes a long time

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 700.000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ext_log_entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `logged_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `object_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `log_date_lookup_idx` (`logged_at`),
  KEY `log_user_lookup_idx` (`username`),
  KEY `log_class_lookup_idx` (`object_class`),
  KEY `log_version_lookup_idx` (`object_id`,`object_class`,`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1219777 ;
```

I try to run the following query:

```
SELECT n0_.id AS id0, n0_.action AS action1, n0_.logged_at AS logged_at2, n0_.object_id AS object_id3, n0_.object_class AS object_class4, n0_.version AS version5, n0_.data AS data6, n0_.username AS username7 
FROM ext_log_entries n0_
WHERE n0_.object_id =275634
AND n0_.object_class = 'My\\MyBundle\\Entity\\Field'
AND n0_.version <=1
ORDER BY n0_.version ASC
```

Here is the MySQL plan:

```
id             1
select_type    SIMPLE
table          n0_
type           ref
possible_keys  log_class_lookup_idx,log_version_lookup_idx
key            log_class_lookup_idx
key_len        767
ref            const
rows           641159
Extra          Using where; Using filesort
```

My query need about 37 seconds to be executed for only 1 row in the result...
I tried to run the same query by deleting my indexes and it goes a little bit faster : about 31 seconds...

I don't understand why my query is taking so much time and why my indexes don't help the performance? Do you know how I can do to have good performance on this query?

Thanks in advance for your help !

EDIT

Here are the cardinalties of the indexes

```
log_date_lookup_idx         BTREE  logged_at        1221578 A       
log_user_lookup_idx         BTREE  username         40      A  YES  
log_class_lookup_idx        BTREE  object_class     1010    A       
log_version_lookup_idx      BTREE  object_id        1221578 A  YES  
                                    object_class    1221578 A   
                                    version         1221578 A
```

Comment: The reason it's running slowly is because it's using the `log_class_lookup_idx` index instead of the `log_version_lookup_idx`. Is the `object_id` column always numeric? If so, why is it a varchar? What's the cardinality (number of unique values) of the `version` column and the `object_id` column?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `SELECT 1 FROM...`... do you not want any column values in your result set?

Comment: I put select 1 for my tests, it doesn't have any meaning. My application will select all the rows of the table.

Comment: @Jon, i added the cardinalities in my original message, thanks for your ansewer !

Comment: I changed my query to be in sync with the one executed by my program, I hope i gave all the needed information. I'm still working on it...

Comment: Try adding an index on version.

Comment: @Mihai I tried, unsuccessfully.... I found an other solution, not the best one but it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, not THE solution, but at least it works for me.

I think it could help anyway all people who are using gedmo loggable and who are lucky (like me) to have objects with only integers IDs.

I changes my column object_id to integer instead of varchar(255). My query now take 0.008 second ! It works for me because i'm sure i'll always have only integers, for people who have varchar, I'm sorry i tried many things but nothing worked....

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ext_log_entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `logged_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `object_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `log_date_lookup_idx` (`logged_at`),
  KEY `log_user_lookup_idx` (`username`),
  KEY `log_class_lookup_idx` (`object_class`),
  KEY `log_version_lookup_idx` (`object_id`,`object_class`,`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1219777 ;
```

Comment: This really doesn't work in all cases. Imagine an entity with a primary key other than `autoincrement`. I.e. primary key is a relation to another entity that has `__toString` method, which returns alphanumeric value. In this case, loggable extension will fail.

Comment: Maybe, i have only auto-increment IDs. But I don't understand your point, how the _toString method will affect our case, we store the ID in teh table not the _toString method result no?

Comment: I assume you're using Doctrine. And when you have a constellation like I explained above (in most cases these are one-to-one relations), then Doctrine itself stores the `__toString` value. I.e. we can observe this behaviour when an entity relates to the `User` entity (we use FOSUserBundle for Symfony) which has a built-in `__toString` method. So logging changes in one-to-one related entity causes Doctrine to store username instead of `id`

Comment: OK thanks for your feedback, I think i'm lucky not to log my user in my loggable log_entries table so i d'ont have any issue.